# How to retrieve position of a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I am using

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFile));
```

to access a log file and read until the end. If I have to reset the program, I would like to restart from the last position. Therefore I need the position of the reader. Is there a way to  retrive the position of the `BufferedReader`?

Comment: I don't think that you can do that for `BufferedReader` but you can try to do it with `RandomAccessFile`

Comment: The problem with RandomAccessFile is, that readLine() does not support the full Unicode, which I need.

Answer (score -1):

you can use BufferedReader.**mark(int readAheadLimit)** This will mark the present position in stream. Subsequent calls to **reset()** will attempt to reposition the stream to this point.

Comment: Doesn't help when he's resetting the entire program.